# Wrongly inserted values to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When i executed the query:

```
"insert into search_option(filename, file_path, keywords)" & _ 
"values('csharp_tutorial.pdf','d:\pdf_record\csharp_tutorial.pdf','C sharp Tutorial')"
```

The value is inserted to the table. But when i `select` the value from the table

```
SELECT * FROM search_option s;
```

will give the result as

```
filename             |     file_path                    |    keywords
                     |                                  |
csharp_tutorial.pdf  | d:pdf_recordcsharp_tutorial.pdf  |  C sharp Tutorial
```

The problem is that `d:\pdf_record\csharp_tutorial.pdf` is inserted as `d:pdf_recordcsharp_tutorial.pdf` why the `\` disappears...?

please suggest me some solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with the `\` if you want to insert `\` to the database you need to add `\\` in code same is in the case of double quotes also if you want double quotes means you need to add `\"`, other examples for escape sequence are [Available Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html)
[image]

hence your code will be:

```
"Insert into search_option(filename, file_path, keywords)" & _ 
"values('csharp_tutorial.pdf','d:\\pdf_record\\csharp_tutorial.pdf','C sharp Tutorial')"
```

if you execute this from vb.net you can use `replace` method to replace `\` with `\\` as

```
FilePath.Replace("\", "\\")
```

Comment: missing `i` in insert

Comment: @  Ganesh_Devlekar : thanks for the correction, i corrected that

Answer (score 1):

That's because `\` character is an escape character used in string literals in your programming language.

So it has nothing to do with mysql, but with your programming language. So check its documentation about how to escape `\`. There is a chance that it's `\\` (slash that escapes the following slash)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
"insert into search_option(filename, file_path, keywords)" & _ 
"values('csharp_tutorial.pdf','d:\\pdf_record\\csharp_tutorial.pdf','C sharp Tutorial')"
```

ESCAPE it